# Why did the distance I have to travel with my buddy Pokemon Lapras DROP from 3 km to 1.25 km?

Tags: pokemon-go

The distance I had to travel with my buddy Pokemon Lapras was originally 3 kilometers after traveling about a total of 40 kilometers with it it dropped to 1.25 kilometers needed to find a candy has anyone else experienced this?

[image]

Comment: Lapras was originally 5km per candy, not 3,right?

Answer (score 1):

During the Halloween event, you will receive 2x the candies for sending pokemon to the Professor and you'll receive 2x the candies, while catching pokemon.

As for your question, all Pokemon Buddy rewards also come in at 1/4 the normal range. So if you have a Lapras it should give you a reward every 0.75km (3km/4).

Halloween Event will take place from somewhere around the 27th until after the 31st.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the Halloween event.